# dynamips stucks on console

Tags: emulators

I have dynamips which stucks when the IOS starts with the following:

```
dynamips -P 7200 c7200-a3jk9s-mz.124-25g.bin

dynamips -P 7200 c7200-a3jk9s-mz.124-25g.bin 
Cisco Router Simulation Platform (version 0.2.16-amd64/Linux stable)
Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Christophe Fillot.
Build date: Dec 21 2016 11:17:47

IOS image file: c7200-a3jk9s-mz.124-25g.bin

mips64_jit_init: unable to create exec area (size 67108864)
NVRAM is empty, setting config register to 0x2142
C7200 instance 'default' (id 0):
  VM Status  : 0
RAM size   : 256 Mb
IOMEM size : 0 Mb
NVRAM size : 128 Kb
NPE model  : npe-400
Midplane   : vxr
IOS image  : c7200-a3jk9s-mz.124-25g.bin

Loading ELF file 'c7200-a3jk9s-mz.124-25g.bin'...
ELF entry point: 0x80008000

C7200 'default': starting simulation (CPU0 PC=0xffffffffbfc00000), JIT enabled.
% Unable to create instruction block for vaddr=0xffffffffbfc00000
insn_page_compile: unable to create JIT block.
VM 'default': unable to compile block for CPU0 PC=0xffffffffbfc00000
```

The IOS is the one reccomended [1]

```
md5sum  c7200-a3jk9s-mz.124-25g.bin 
3a78cb61831b3ef1530f7402f5986556  c7200-a3jk9s-mz.124-25g.bin
```

I've also tried by specifing the amount of Ram (256) as stated in the doc, the idle-pc value, as well as a compressed and uncompressed IOS.
Also, i've tried in hypervisor mode and connecting via dynagen...same result.

```
dynamips version: 0.2.16 on x86_64
```

What else can I try?

[1] http://docs.gns3.com/1-kBrTplBltp9P3P-AigoMzlDO-ISyL1h3bYpOl5Q8mQ/#h.p7dwjvw8qyi0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to JIT compiler.
Running dynamips with -j made it work, but of course it was too slow.
Since the distribution I was using is alpine (www.alpinelinux.org) and it's use PAX, i had to paxmark /usr/bin/dynamips.
The latest version of dynamips in Alpine is fixed since the binary it's paxmarked in the package.